# How to configure .net core 3.1 appsettings to run tests on Github actions

Tags: .net-core, integration-testing, github-actions

I'm developing a web API using .Net core 3.1 trying to integrate it to Github Actions to run the integration tests when a pull request is created.

I'm using the [secrets manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to store my API tokens and other sensitive data in development mode

*secrets.json*

```
{
    "Firebase": {
        "Login": "foo@bar.com",
        "Password": "FooBar",
        "Url": "foobar.firebaseapp.com "
    },

}
```

And on GitHub I've tried to add Secrets([GitHub secrets = environment variables](https://help.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/creating-and-storing-encrypted-secrets)) with the same names I have on my secrets JSON but it hasn't worked.
The GitHub secrets that I've created are like

```
(KEY - VALUE)
LOGIN - foo@bar.com 
PASSWORD - FooBar
```

And on my test class, I'm invoking the environment variables using the following configuration before the tests

```
public MyTestClass()
{           
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder() 
        .AddUserSecrets<MyTestClass>()
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    Configuration = builder.Build();
    _settings = Configuration.Get<Settings>();
}
```

And my .yml looks like

```
jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: 3.1.300
    - name: Nuget
      run: dotnet restore
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore
    - name: Test
      run: dotnet test --no-restore --verbosity normal
      env: 
        LOGIN: ${{ secrets.LOGIN }}
        PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.PASSWORD}}
        URL: ${{ secrets.URL}}
```

How can I load the Settings when executing inside GitHub Actions?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if i'm not stating the obvious (you didn't mention how you start test app), but GitHub secrets **!=** environment variables. They **can** be, if user wants that, but it's **not** done automagically.

```yaml
- run: program.exe
```

In this case, program won't know login/password, as there's no way it can access this data.

```yaml
- run: program.exe
  env:
   LOGIN:    ${{ secrets.LOGIN }}
   PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.PASSWORD }}
```

In this case, program will know login/password, as secrets are "converted" to environment variables, which application can see.

```yaml
- run: program.exe --login=${{ secrets.LOGIN }} --password=${{ secrets.PASSWORD }}
```

In this case, program will know login/password, as secrets are passed via command line arguments, which application can see. Environment variables remain unchanged in this case.

Another option is to keep encrypted *secrets.json* in repository, and decrypt it when workflow is running; see [docs](https://help.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/creating-and-storing-encrypted-secrets#limits-for-secrets) for details.

Comment: He @Samira, thanks for the insights, I've updated my question with my current .yml. I'm wondering if I'm missing something on the test setup on the c# side or if I have to setup the environment variables in a way they match my json config

Comment: So the solution ended up being related to how I was creating the env variables. I had to make them match my settings class structure. In this case Settings.Firebase.Login has env variable = FIREBASE__LOGIN